# How to catch error in nested Promise when async/await is used

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
async function thisThrows() {
  return new Promise((resove, reject) => {
    throw new Error("Thrown from thisThrows()");
  });
}

async function thatThrows() {
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      await thisThrows();
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('reached here');
    resolve(true);
  });
}

async function run() {
  try {
    await thatThrows();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('catch error', e);
  } finally {
    console.log('We do cleanup here');
  }
}

run();
```

I have situation where i don't want the statement **console.log('reached here'); resolve(true);** should execute if error in thrown by previous statements.  I tried several combinations but no luck. run method should catch the error. In my above code run method catch method not executed

Comment: Do not use `new Promise` in `thatThrows`. It's never rejected.

Comment: @Bergi After removing as per your suggestion, I see console statement "reached here".

Comment: `async function thatThrows() { await thisThrows(); console.log('reached here'); }` will not log "reached here" if `thisThrows` actually throws (returns a rejected promise).

Comment: Notice that also `thisThrows` should be either `function thisThrows() { return new Promise((resove, reject) => { reject(new Error("…")); }); }`  or just `async function thisThrows() { throw new Error("…"); }`

Comment: @Bergi, I executed the code but the problem is neither run method **catch** nor **finally**  block gets executed. I need to get executed either of these statement

Comment: Then you're not running the code from my comments but still the broken one that doesn't settle the `new Promise` in case of an error.

Comment: @Bergi Please find the jsfiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cebsushant/65ojLx0f/1/)

Comment: If possible could you please send me the working code.

Comment: That's the original broken code from your question, which does not run for the reasons explained in the duplicate. Understand the explanation, then fix your code as I outlined in the comments.